# Ruby with missing end. Or extra end?

Tags: ruby, loops, syntax

I saw this one answered before, but I just can NOT find the missing END here. It's a simple Ruby program for learning. I went back and typed it exactly as they had it. Still getting the error. Where is the end missing????

```
puts "Welcome to 'Get My Number!'"
print "What's your name? "

input = gets

name = input.chomp

puts "Welcome, #{name}!"

# Store a random number for the player to guess.

puts "I've got a random number between 1 and 100."
puts "Can you guess it?"
target = rand(100) + 1

# Track how many guesses the player has made.

num_guesses = 0

# Track whether player has guessed correctly.

guessed_it = false

Until num_guesses == 10 || guessed_it

  puts "You've got #{10 - num_guesses} guesses left."
  print "Make a guess: "
  guess = gets.to_i

  num_guesses += 1

# Compare guess to target and print appropriate message.

  if guess < target
    puts "Oops. Your guess was LOW."
  elsif guess > target
    puts "Oops. Your guess was HIGH."
  elsif guess == target
    puts "Good job, #{name}!"
    puts "You guessed my number in #{num_guesses} guesses!"
    guessed_it = true
  end

 end

 #If the player didn't guess in time, show the target number.

 unless guessed_it
    puts "Sorry. You didn't get my number. (It was #{target}.)"
```

Comment: 1. The `Until` loop needs to be `until` 2. The `unless` conditional is missing an `end`.

Comment: You need to put an `end` at the end.

Comment: An easy way to troubleshoot this type of problem when you're just getting started is to comment out every line, then uncomment one line or one block at a time until the error is triggered again.

Answer (score 2):

I think problem is in `if` and `elsif` block. Change it to `case`. Also it’s more clean and easy to understand.

For example, in this way:

```
case 
when guess < target then puts "Oops. Your guess was LOW."
when guess > target then puts "Oops. Your guess was HIGH."
when guess == target then
   puts "Good job, #{name}!"
   puts "You guessed my number in #{num_guesses} guesses!"
   guessed_it = true
end
```

I hope it useful for you.

Comment: This seems much cleaner. The problem was the capitalized until and the missing end. I will probably use this case much more in the future, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As Tom Lord mentioned, you're missing an `end` at the end and the keyword `Until` should be all lowercase per Sagar Pandya. Your application, in it's entirety, should be as below.

```
puts "Welcome to 'Get My Number!'"
print "What's your name? "

input = gets

name = input.chomp

puts "Welcome, #{name}!"

# Store a random number for the player to guess.

puts "I've got a random number between 1 and 100."
puts "Can you guess it?"
target = rand(100) + 1

# Track how many guesses the player has made.

num_guesses = 0

# Track whether player has guessed correctly.

guessed_it = false

until num_guesses == 10 || guessed_it

  puts "You've got #{10 - num_guesses} guesses left."
  print "Make a guess: "
  guess = gets.to_i

  num_guesses += 1

# Compare guess to target and print appropriate message.

  if guess < target
    puts "Oops. Your guess was LOW."
  elsif guess > target
    puts "Oops. Your guess was HIGH."
  elsif guess == target
    puts "Good job, #{name}!"
    puts "You guessed my number in #{num_guesses} guesses!"
    guessed_it = true
  end
end

#If the player didn't guess in time, show the target number.

unless guessed_it
  puts "Sorry. You didn't get my number. (It was #{target}.)"
end
```

Comment: The until and last end were the problems, alright! Thank you. It runs perfectly now.